# I want to print Count using Groupby and Left join in linq

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I having two list or table as per below:
Query:

```
 var q = db.tbl_User_to_CustomerMast
     .Where(i => i.fk_Membership_ID == m.MembershipID)
     .Join(
         db.tbl_CustomerMast, 
         u => u.fk_Customer_ID, 
         c => c.CustomerID, 
         (u, c) => new { UserCustomer = u, Customer = c })
     .Where(i => i.UserCustomer.fk_Store_ID == shopid).ToList();
```

Output:

```
 List A:
    User_Customer_ID        Name
    ===================================
    1                       XYZ
    2                       ABC
```

Query:

```
var rewards = q.Join(
        db.tbl_RewardAwardMast, 
        i => i.UserCustomer.User_Customer_ID, 
        j => j.fk_Customer_UserID, 
       (i, j) => new { Customer = i, Reward = j })
   .Where(i => i.Reward.RewardDate >= i.Customer.UserCustomer.Membership_Start)
   .GroupBy(i => i.Reward.fk_Customer_UserID)
   .Select(i => new { CustomerID = i.Key, RewardCount = i.Count()})
   .ToList();
```

Output:

```
List B:
User_Customer_ID     RewardCount
===================================
1                       5
```

Here is  final Output Table

```
User_Customer_ID        Name       RewardCount
===============================================
1                       XYZ            5
2                       ABC            0
```

If I want to check that which user_customer_ID has less than 5 Reward Count, How I will Check:

Query:

```
var final = q.GroupJoin(
        rewards, 
        i => i.UserCustomer.User_Customer_ID, 
        j => j.CustomerID, 
        (i, j) => new { Customer = i, Reward = j.DefaultIfEmpty() })
    .Select(i => new { Count = i.Reward, id = i.Customer.UserCustomer.User_Customer_ID })
    .ToList();

var final1 = final.Where(i => i.Count < m.MembershipMinVisit.Value).ToList();
```

Error:
Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' and 'int'

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` will give you null when there's no `Reward`. Trying to get `RewardCount` out of that results in a `NullReferenceException`. Since you're using left join in the first place, I assume that you do expect to have null values in there, so you should handle the case properly. Also, as an aside, using `FirstOrDefault` is probably a bad idea.

Comment: I remove firstordefault and try with another approach, but getting different error.

Comment: @Luaan Actually `DefaultIfEmpty` will result in `Reward` not being empty, but possibly containing a `null` value.

Comment: I want to just compare two values and want final result with having less than 5 value

Comment: I think, I must return count in select. but i dont know how to return it

Comment: Stop just guessing around. You need to understand what the code is doing, otherwise you're only really randomly trying solutions, hoping that one will work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a group join here as for each customer you need a single result (reward). Also because you need only customers with rewards < 5, an inner join using that condition wil give you what you want:

```
var final = q.Join(                               // Join instead of GroupJoin
        rewards.Where(r => r.RewardCount < 5),    // filter out rewards >= 5
        i => i.UserCustomer.User_Customer_ID, 
        j => j.CustomerID, 
       (i, j) => new { Customer = i, Reward = j })
    .Select(i => new { 
        Reward = i.Reward,                            // 'Count' is a bad name
                                                      // it is still the reward object
        id = i.Customer.UserCustomer.User_Customer_ID
    })
    .ToList();
```

In your original query, `Count` (bad name) is a collection (`IEnumerable`) of awards, that's why you get that error. To fix it, you have to check that the single returned reward is not null (to filter out users without rewards at all, because you use a left join) and that it has a `RewardCount` less that `5`:

```
var final1 = final.Where(i => i.Count.Single() != null &&
                              i.Count.Single().RewardCount < 5)
             .ToList();
```